# Event driven nature of nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

from the [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) the first tine about nodejs is,

> As an asynchronous event-driven JavaScript runtime, Node.js is designed to build scalable network applications.

and considering the following snippet,

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
      return;
   }
   console.log(data.toString());
});
```

My question is,

Does nodejs always (somewhere using its internal libraries) emit an event whenever it encounters an asynchronous operation ?

Comment: https://codeforgeek.com/asynchronous-programming-in-node-js/ this can be helpful read

Comment: no, asynchronous operation does not always emit an event